# 2 different ways of sorting in mysql according value column

Tags: mysql

I've got table in MySQL like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj7Jc.jpg). I need to sort the records by **active**, **start_date** and **start_time** column - probably this way:

```
->order('active DESC, start_date, start_time');
```

that means records with **active = true** are on the top. Date and time are the nearest to current. The problem is - I need to change **start_date**, **start_time** sorting by DESC when active = false.

Is it possible to do this?

I am sorry about my english. I hope you'll got this.

Comment: If your table is compact you may use something like `ORDER BY ... , CASE WHEN active THEN 0+start_date ELSE 0-start_date, ...`. start_date is converted to numeric representation in shown expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. This is what I needed:

```
ORDER BY
active DESC,
CASE WHEN active = 0 THEN NULL ELSE start_date END,
CASE WHEN active = 0 THEN NULL ELSE start_time END,
start_date DESC,
start_time DESC
```